# Roles and Permissions with Spatie, Laravel and VueJs

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, laravel-7

I am using `Laravel` and `VueJs` for my app, and I want to integrate a section for roles and permissions and for that I am using [Spatie](https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-permission/v3/introduction/spatie).

In app, each user can have multiple Roles (like: admin, teacher, editor) and each role has some permissions.

I tried some stuff from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53312875/vue-js-with-laravel-permission) , Shuyi's answer but I get some errors.

The questions is how can I check roles in `VueJS`?

**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TeachersController extends Controller
{
    function check($permissionName) {
        if (! Auth::user()->hasPermissionTo($permissionName)) {
             abort(403);
        }
        return response('', 204);
     }
}
```

**web.php**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
   Route::get('/permission/{permissionName}', 'PermissionController@check');
});
```

**app.js**

```
Vue.mixin("can", (permissionName) => {
    let hasAccess;
    axios.get(`/permission/${permissionName}`)
        .then(() => {
            hasAccess = true;
        })
        .catch(() => {
            hasAccess = false;
        });
    return hasAccess;
});
```

App.vue

```
<template>
    <button v-if="can('write-stuff')">Just a test!</button>
</template>
```

> Property or method "can" is not defined on the instance but referenced
> during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the
> data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the
> property. See:
> https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not defining you mixin as global, you have to inject it in the component you want to use, as explained in the **[Vue Mixins docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#Global-Mixin)**

**Per component registration:**

> ```
> // define a mixin object
> var myMixin = {
>   created: function () {
>     this.hello()
>   },
>   methods: {
>     hello: function () {
>       console.log('hello from mixin!')
>     }
>   }
> }
>
> // define a component that uses this mixin
> var Component = Vue.extend({
>   mixins: [myMixin]
> })
> ```

**Global registration (will be available in all components )**

> ```
> // inject a handler for `myOption` custom option
> Vue.mixin({
>   created: function () {
>     var myOption = this.$options.myOption
>     if (myOption) {
>       console.log(myOption)
>     }
>   }
> })
>
> new Vue({
>   myOption: 'hello!'
> })
> ```